# How does an event listener within a for loop keep running all the time?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to understand how an event listener within a for loop keeps on running even after the loop has been completed. For example, in the code below the for loop should only run twice. When the value of i becomes 2 the loop should end. But the buttons continue working no matter how many times I click them. I want to understand the logic behind this.

```
<button class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn">Button 2</button>

<script>
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert("Hello");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The loop only runs twice and in doing so adds event handlers to 2 buttons. But once those event handlers are attached they remain attached until removed, which you do not do. It's rare to want event handlers to only work a small number of times, usually you want the button to do whatever the thing is you want *whenever it is clicked* and no matter how many times it is clicked.

Comment: The event listener listens for events, the loop just informs javascript of which classes to listen to. So in this case the loop tells the browser, listen to any click events on button 1 and button 2.

Comment: It's adding an eventlistener that listens to the click event once in the for loop, it's not running all the time, just when a button is pressed, it checks if there is a listener for the click event (and since they got added in the for loop), it calls the eventhandler. There is nothing magic about it :)

Answer (score 0):

An event listener doesn't run continuously. When you add an event listener, you're registering a callback function that should be run when something happens in the future. In your example, it's telling the browser, "When there's a click on this button, call this function."

The browser itself is running continuously, converting user interactions into these event. When the user clicks, the browser scans its list of event listeners to see if any of them include the portion of the browser window where they clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You've added an event listener to watch a certain action, if you no longer want to listen to this action you have to remove the listener.

Your loop does indeed end after running twice, you can check that by writing a `console.log('runs: ', i + 1)`, but you have subscribed to an event inside the loop. It means that unless you unsubscribe from it, you will keep listening to the event.

To unsubscribe:

```js
document.removeEventListener("click", function () {
  alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: this won't actually remove the event handler - you need to remove the exact same function reference as the one added.

Comment: Oh yea I wanted to assign it to a variable at first but I was wondering if refactoring this code too much would add complexity for receiver. Your point is excellent here though

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear, and a little bit weird why would you want to end event after a for loop, because here you did nothing when you end it due the fast of for loop execution.

But if you mean to make the user to be able to click the buttons once, use this:

```html
<button class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn">Button 2</button>

<script>
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert("Hello");
    }, { once: true });
  }
</script>
```

I don't think that's the case, but that's what has come to my mind.